# Read dataframes from files of different subfolders

Tags: python, pandas

I have 12 different directories, looking something like that:

```
directories = ['FOLDER/subfolder01/*.csv', 'FOLDER/subfolder02/*csv', ... ]
```

12 subfolders within one major FOLDER, each one containing a set of csv files with the same data format.

I'd like to loop over it and somehow read the dataframes within each subfolder and then continue with the plots.

Is there a way to set the subfolders as indexes over which I can manipulate with the files?

Comment: You can create a field called `source` with the filepath as values and index it.

Answer (score 0):

```
from glob import glob
directory_dfs = {directory_name: load_csvs_from_directory(directory_name)
                 for directory_name in glob('FOLDER/subfolder*/')}
```

Then just encapsulate your logic for how to read all the CSV's from a directory into the `load_csvs_from_directory` function, and voila, you have a labelled collection of the DataFrames built from the data in each directory.